# Openlayers 5 zoom control has + but zoom out button has "âˆ’" - any idea why?

Tags: openlayers

Doesn't seem to matter what browser I'm using.  I have the prebuilt ol.js v5.2.0.  As well as the prebuilt ol.css

Here is the code to create the view, it doesn't get any simpler:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ol.css" type="text/css">

    <script src="ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style="width:90%; height:100%;">
    <div id="map" class="map" ></div>
    <script>

      var tiledLayer = 
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          extent: [-8222827, 4994547, -7968767, 5177517],
          source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: <my url>,
            params: {'LAYERS': 'MyTestLayer', 'TILED': true},
            serverType: 'geoserver',
            transition: 0
          })
        })

      var layers = [
        tiledLayer
      ];
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: layers,
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          zoom: 15
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I inspect the elements of the zoom control in the browser debugger, here they are:

```
<div class="ol-zoom ol-unselectable ol-control">
   <button title="Zoom in" class="ol-zoom-in" type="button">+</button>
   <button title="Zoom out" class="ol-zoom-out" type="button">âˆ’</button></div>
```

Notice the odd characters where it should just say "-".
A quick google of these characters indicate they may be "Unicode 8722 – the MINUS SIGN"

If so, how do I get my browser to display it properly?  Is this my issue or an Openlayers issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a problem related to the charset used by your browser. I ran into the same problem, adding the `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag in the head of the html file will fix it.

You might check out [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783494/openlayers-5-1-3-damaged-zoom-out-button-in-quick-start-example) for more information.

Comment: That was it!  I was hoping it was something simple I was missing.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

We have just updated our website from OpenLayers 2 to OpenLayers 6. On our test server the [+/-] rendered just fine. The [+/-] rendered with the stray character in ol6, but was ok in ol2. This fixup took all of 20 minutes to resolve and fix.

Note the `<meta charset="utf=8">` had to be the first `<meta...>` tag in the HTML file.

This did not work:

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <meta name="hand-generated html (primitive, aint it?)">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
```

This did work:

```
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <meta name="hand-generated html (primitive, aint it?)">
```

Comment: That is useful to note, it should like like:
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">